# How format duration hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: java

I need format `java.time.Duration` like

```
T05:00:00 (hours:minutes:seconds).
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you could convert to a string you can use

> String.format();

for this.

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleDateFormat class is within Java's utility library and it is what most people use:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Time {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      //instance of the time, date      
      Date date = new Date();
      //format it however you like.
      String strDateFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
      //The SimpleDateFormat class allows the actual time format
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
      //use the sdf object to format
      System.out.println(sdf.format(date));


    }

}
```

Comment: question about java.time.Duration